# Getting an input from a form using JavaScript in html

Tags: javascript

I have created an input form in html and  trying to get the value of this input field using JavaScript.

When I alert it, to check if it works,  it returns an empty value. The code is below. What could be the problem?

```js
var num1 = document.getElementById('numb1').value;
var num2 = document.getElementById('numb2').value;
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
var show = document.getElementById('shows');
for (let i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
  if(button[i].id == 'plus'){
    button[i].onclick = function (){
      var a = num1 + num2;
      alert(a);
    }   
  } 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="set">
    <input type="text" id="numb1" placeholder="enter a number" >
    <input type="text" id="numb2" placeholder="enter a number">
    <div class="buttons">
      <button id="plus">+</button>
      <button id="min">-</button>
      <button id="mult">*</button>
      <button id="div">/</button>
    </div>
    <div class="show" id="shows"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This because you have kept following lines outside the callback function:

```
var num1 = document.getElementById('numb1').value;
var num2 = document.getElementById('numb2').value;
```

So, `num1` and `num2` are initialized only once i.e. at page load-time. At this time both (`num1` and `num2`) having empty value. Hence it not being initialized every time and showing and empty value.

**Note:**

- Consider to parse input text into numeric values using `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()`
- You should keep your `JavaScript` code in `<script>` tag.

Following is corrected code snippet:

```js
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
var show = document.getElementById('shows');
for (let i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
 if(button[i].id == 'plus'){
  button[i].onclick = function (){
   var num1 = document.getElementById('numb1').value;
   var num2 = document.getElementById('numb2').value;
    var a = parseFloat(num1 )+ parseFloat(num2);
    alert(a);
  }   
 } 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="set">
  <input type="text" id="numb1" placeholder="enter a number" >
  <input type="text" id="numb2" placeholder="enter a number">
  <div class="buttons">
   <button id="plus">+</button>
   <button id="min">-</button>
   <button id="mult">*</button>
   <button id="div">/</button>
  </div>
  <div class="show" id="shows"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value of the inputs when the button is clicked, not when the page loads.

```
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
var show = document.getElementById('shows');
for (let i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
if(button[i].id == 'plus'){
    button[i].onclick = function (){
        var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('numb1').value);
        var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('numb2').value);
        var a = num1 + num2;
        alert(a);
    }   
} 
}
```

The above code will get the value of the inputs when the button is clicked. I also presumed you would want the values converting to float, if this is not the case then remove the parseFloat function to make it:

```
var num1 = document.getElementById('numb1').value;
var num2 = document.getElementById('numb2').value;
```